# Use Foreign Key to access other object Django in form's clean method

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

I want to access other objects of foreign key.

models.py

```
from django.db import models

class Box(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200,null=True)
    apples= models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    banana = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    mango = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Buyer(models.Model):
    name_of_buyer = models.CharField(max_length=200,null=True)
    address_of_buyer = models.CharField(max_length=200,null=True)
    interested_in = models.ForeignKey(Box,on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True)
    Pickup_dt = models.DateField(null=True)
    Pickup_time = models.CharField(max_length=80,null=True)
```

forms.py

```
from .models import Price

class Sale(forms.ModelForm):
    def clean_interested_in(self):
        buyer_interested_in_box = self.cleaned_data['interested_in']
        # if the selected box contains less than 10 apples, 10 bananas and 10 mangos:
               raise forms.ValidationError('Not enough fruits.Please select another box')         
    class Meta:
        model = Buyer
        widgets = {
            'Pickup_dt': forms.DateInput(attrs={'class':'datepicker'}),
            'Pickup_time': forms.DateInput(attrs={'class':'timepicker'}),
        }
        fields = '__all__'
```

How can I validate this form by using the foreign key id?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use your `clean_interested_in` method. In the method, `self.cleaned_data['interested_in']` should be the related object.

```
def clean_interested_in(self):
    buyer_interested_in_box = self.cleaned_data['interested_in']
    if ((buyer_interested_in_box.apples is None or buyer_interested_in_box.apples < 10) or 
            (buyer_interested_in_box.bananas is None or buyer_interested_in_box.bananas < 10) or
            (buyer_interested_in_box. mangos is None or buyer_interested_in_box. mangos < 10)):
       raise forms.ValidationError('Not enough fruits. Please select another box')
    return buyer_interested_in_box
```

Note that you need to check whether the fruit values are `None`. If you change the model field to `null=False` then you won't need this check and you can simplify the code.

Comment: Thank you so much!